# ArrayList printing values missing?

Tags: java, arraylist

1. When entering my games in this format:

   test : 120 : 120
   game : 120 : 120
   quit
2. My txt file is only showing my first entry and not my second entry, in my text file it is displaying this below:

   Player : adam

   ---

   Game: test , score=  120 , minutes played=  120
3. But I want it to show:

   Game: test , score=  120 , minutes played=  120
   Game: feff, score=  3412, minutes played=  434

So far my code is:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Generator {
   private static char[] input;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] minutesPlayed = new int [100];
       String gamerName, gamerReport;
       String[] gameNames = new String[100];
       int[] highScores = new int[100];
       @SuppressWarnings("resource")
       Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("-------------- Game Score Report Generator --------------");
       System.out.println("     ");
       System.out.print("Enter your Name.");
       System.out.println("   ");
       gamerName = Scan.nextLine();

       boolean isEmpty = gamerName == null || gamerName.trim().length() == 0;
       if (isEmpty) {
           System.out.print("Enter your Name.");
           gamerName = Scan.nextLine();
       }

       System.out.println("Enter details in this format - " + " --> Game : Achievement Score : Minutes Played");
       System.out.println("    ");
       System.out.println("Game : Achievement Score : Minutes Played");

       gamerReport = Scan.nextLine();
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);     
       List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();    
       String word;                                  
       while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {               
         word = scanner.nextLine();                  
         if (word != null) {                        
           word = word.trim();                      
           if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {      
             break;                                  
           }
           al.add(word);                             

         } else {
           break;                                   
         }
       }

       String[] splitUpReport; 
       splitUpReport = gamerReport.split(":"); 
       int i = 0;

       gameNames[i] = splitUpReport[0];
       highScores[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[1].trim() );
       minutesPlayed[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[2].trim());

       try
      {
         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Gaming Report Data.txt", true));
         writer.println("Player : " + gamerName);
         writer.println();
         writer.println("--------------------------------");
         writer.println();
         String[] report = gamerReport.split(":");
         writer.println("Game: " + report[0] + ", score= " +report[1] + ", minutes played= " +report[2]);
         writer.close();

     } catch (IOException e)
     {
       System.err.println("File does not exist!");
     }    
   }                   
public static char[] getInput() {
   return input;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first score input is being stored in a variable called `gamerReport`, but every score input after that is added to an ArrayList called `al`. At the end of your code, you are only pulling data from the `gamerReport` variable (which only contains the first score).

You might want to rewrite the score input code to add all of its code to the `al` ArrayList during the loop, then have the text output section iterate through `al` afterwards.

## Example code for capturing and storing input

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
String word = "";

while (true) {
    word = scanner.nextLine();
    if (word != null) word = word.trim();
    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) break;
    al.add(word);
}

System.out.println(al);
```

This code gets around the problem of having your data stored in two different variables (it's now all stored in `al`, and `gamerReport` has been removed as it is not needed). To print this out to a file later, you should iterate over it (with something like `for (String str : al) { ... }`).

Note that this code is not user-proof at all. It might be wise to look into regular expressions to prevent the user from inputting invalid data.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do so, could you possibly point me in the right direction.

Comment: For gathering input, you can use a while loop that terminates when the user enters 'quit'.

Comment: Ahh still not sure how to work it ight ahve to redo the whole program.